# How to get links on a webpage using mechanize and open those links

Tags: python, mechanize

I want to use mechanize with python to get all the links of the page, and then open the links.How can I do it?

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example from the project's [page](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/):

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open("http://www.example.com/")

# ...

# .links() optionally accepts the keyword args of .follow_/.find_link()
for link in br.links(url_regex="python.org"):
    print link
    br.follow_link(link)  # takes EITHER Link instance OR keyword args
    br.back()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Browser` object in `mechanize` has a `links` method that will retrieve all the links on the page.